# alert() changes functionality of OL3 zoom

Tags: javascript, zooming, openlayers, alert, openlayers-3

I've created a map with several layers and want to zoom to the extent of one of these layers (map_coverage_S), so simply like this:

```
extent = map_coverage_S.getSource().getExtent();
view.fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());
```

Unfortunately **the zoom does not work**, but if I put an alert in between these two lines:

```
extent = map_coverage_S.getSource().getExtent();
alert(extent);
view.fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());
```

**it works!** 
However, the alert is (Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity). When I put a second alert, it returns the proper coordinates, like I would expect. So it seems as if an alert seems to "refresh" my map. How can I get a solution without an alert? I already tried different types of timer and sleep-functions, or outsourcing functions but only the alert leads to a proper result. 
Can anyone help me?
Thanks,
Arne

Answer (score 0):

**Ah, I already solved the problem on my own!**

I found the solution in triggering an event:

```
map_coverage_S.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    map.getView().fitExtent(map_coverage_S.getSource().getExtent(), (map.getSize()));

});
```

Best regards,
Arne